# Background image for tableview Titanium

Tags: titanium

I am making application which requires to implement TableView.

I want to apply background image to tableview.

Can anybody help me to resolve this issue.
I am using below code to create Table view

```
Titanium.UI.setBackgroundColor('#FFF');

var win = Titanium.UI.currentWindow;


var data = [
{title:'Owner Description:'+'   '+Titanium.App.Properties.getString("latitude"),hasChild:false,color:'blue', selectedColor:'#fff',  setFont:10},
{title:'TerminalDescription:'+'   '+Titanium.App.Properties.getString("TerminalDesc"),hasChild:false},
{title:'Address:'+'   '+Titanium.App.Properties.getString("address"),hasChild:false},
{title:'City:'+'   '+Titanium.App.Properties.getString("city"),hasChild:false},
{title:'State:'+'   '+Titanium.App.Properties.getString("state"),hasChild:false},
{title:'Zip:'+'   '+Titanium.App.Properties.getString("Zip"),hasChild:false},
{title:'Surcharge Amount:'+'   '+Titanium.App.Properties.getString("Charge"),hasChild:false},
];


var tableview = Titanium.UI.createTableView({   
    data:data,
    opacity:'.4',
    maxRowHeight:'20',
    //Set BG transparent
    backgroundColor:'transparent',
    backgroundImage:'Default.png', 
    //Set row color - white
    rowBackgroundColor:'white'

});


win.add(tableview);
```

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you want a single background in the table view, or you want this background to appear in each row of the table view?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want a single image as a background to the whole TableView. Have a `backgroundImage` set in the parent view and for `TableView` set the `backgroundColor` to `transparent`. Following is your code modified for the same:

```
var win = Titanium.UI.currentWindow;
setBackgroundImage('Default.png');

var data = [ ... ];

var tableview = Titanium.UI.createTableView({
    data:data, 
    maxRowHeight:'20', 
    backgroundColor:'transparent', //Set BG transparent  
    rowBackgroundColor:'white'
});

win.add(tableview);
```

[Reference](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/3991/tableview-background-image)